# How to fix persistent "stale file handle" for mounted network attached storage

Tags: ubuntu, mount, cifs, nas

I have a Linux server running Ubuntu that I am trying to have our network attached storage drive successfully set up on. I'm able to mount it fine, but the issue is that within a few hours the folder becomes inaccessible, with a "stale file handle" error. I can easily fix this by unmounting the drive and remounting it, but this requires root privileges, and so the users of the server aren't able to fix this on their own.

Is there any reason this would be continually happening? And if so, how might fix it or have a workaround?

My mount command is:

`sudo mount -t cifs -o username=MYUSER,workgroup=d,vers=2.0,uid=user,gid=user //NASLOCATION /home/user/MNT_DIR`

I use this same command for my personal computer, and I get a stale file handle every month or so, but not every few hours.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why the explicit version downgrade? What's the nature of the connection between server and NAS?

Comment: This is just the version recommended by our IT department, but it gives the same issue regardless of 2.0 or 3.0. This is all on a university network, behind a firewall, and the server is connected via ethernet cable.

Comment: hm, OK, then that's a separate issue (generally, you want >= 3.0 when possible, as it has security and performance benefits; but that's not going to solve your problem, it seems!)